# Using python with selenium webdriver doesn't work with every wireless connection

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

my script works very well when I use it at my offices (wifi connection). But when I get home and I use my personal wifi or any other wifi, it doesn't work...

Could you please help me ??

Extracted from general.log

`ERROR [2018-08-11 21:31:18] [mehdidouache] Message: Can not connect to the Service /Users/Mehdi/Desktop/InstaPy/assets/chromedriver
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Mehdi/Desktop/InstaPy/instapy/instapy.py", line 299, in set_selenium_local_session
chrome_options=chrome_options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in init
self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 102, in start
raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /Users/Mehdi/Desktop/InstaPy/assets/chromedriver`